# How to connect to cloudSQL proxy from Prisma in Google Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql, prisma, cloud-sql-proxy

### I have a microservices project which has:

- user-service
- post-service

### Let's talk about the user-service to explain the problem:

After deploying the k8s objects like deployment that contains the user image, pods are created and each pod contains the user container and the cloud-sql-proxy container in a sidecar pattern.

Now inside this pod, I am using Prisma inside the user container to connect to the cloud sql proxy container inside the same pod on this url: `postgresql://username:password@localhost/db_name?host=/cloudsql/gcp_project:us-central1:db`

### Problem:

When I log the user-service pod, I find this error:

`Error: P1013: The provided database string is invalid. invalid port number in database URL. Please refer to the documentation in https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference/connection-urls for constructing a correct connection string. In some cases, certain characters must be escaped. Please check the string for any illegal characters.`

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

# Copy the start.sh into the container
COPY start.sh .

# Make the shell script executable
RUN chmod +x start.sh

# Execute the shell script
CMD ["/bin/sh", "start.sh"]
```

#### Inside start.sh

#!/bin/bash

cd src/

npx prisma db push

cd ..

npm start

Inside the src/ directory I have the prisma/ dir.

#### Note: I have also tried replacing ':' with %3A in the DB string param, but it did not work.

### Deployment File

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-depl
  namespace: social-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: user
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: user
          image: <image_name>
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "500m"
              memory: "512Mi"
            requests:
              cpu: "250m"
              memory: "256Mi"
        - name: cloud-sql-proxy
          image: gcr.io/cloud-sql-connectors/cloud-sql-proxy:2.1.0
          args:
            - "--structured-logs"
            - "--port=5432"
            - "PROJECT_ID:asia-south1:POSTGRES_INSTANCE_NAME"
            - "--credentials-file=/secrets/service_account.json"

          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cloudsql-sa-volume
              mountPath: /secrets/
              readOnly: true
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "768Mi"
              cpu: "500m"

      volumes:
        - name: cloudsql-sa-volume
          secret:
            secretName: cloudsql-sa

---
# Cluster IP service for user service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: user-srv
  namespace: social-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: user
  ports:
    - name: user
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5001
      targetPort: 5001
```

I have also checked if the cloud-sql-proxy container is running or not by logging it, and the message that it is ready for connections.

When I run this command: `npx prisma db push` using the shell script, I am expecting prisma to successfully connect to the cloudsql proxy container which will connect to the cloudsql instance on google cloud.

Comment: In the GKE deployment YAML for the proxy sidecar, did you set the port? (there's a place where in the args section you need to set "--port=<PORT>"). If you didn't set that, the proxy isn't listening on any ports I don't believe, which might be giving you this error.

Comment: Can you please share your deployment YAML that showcases your cloud-sql-proxy sidecar? Are you deploying the sidecar to connect with Unix sockets or TCP? If unix sockets then your URL looks correct to me, if the Proxy is expecting TCP then you will need to configure the port as mentioned in above comment.

Comment: @GabeWeiss yes I have mentioned the PORT which is the default here 5432.

Comment: @JackWotherspoon I have edited my post, check once. Please tell me how I can fix it :')

Comment: For grins and giggles...remove the `?host=/cloudsql/gcp_project:us-central1:db` from the connection string and see what happens? I want to see if there's somethin funky goin on with the Unix socket vs. an ordinary TCP/IP connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bit of confusion happening here.

The Cloud SQL Proxy can be deployed to connect to Cloud SQL via two different options:

a) [TCP connection over a port](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy#configuring-port) (default)

b) [Unix domain socket](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy#configuring-unix-domain-sockets) (using the `--unix-socket` flag)

It seems as though your configuration is deploying the Cloud SQL Proxy to connect via TCP connection (using `--port`) but your application (Prisma config) is attempting to connect via a Unix socket (by using host as query param, [Prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/postgresql#connecting-via-sockets)).

Your deployment YAML looks fine as is to me, it should successfully setup the proxy to listen for a TCP connection on `127.0.0.1:5432` of your pod. You should be able to just update your application and Prisma URL accordingly to the following:

```
postgresql://username:password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name
```

Comment: **FINALLY IT'S WORKING!!!**

For the last username that I used, it had a password which contained a **special character '#'**.

But for the new password that I created for the new username, I used **plain text in password** (No special characters) and it is working just fine.

My cloudsql instance is now connected to user container via cloud sql proxy container :)

Comment: I also followed this url format as suggested by Jack and Gabe:
`postgresql://username:password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name`

Comment: awesome! Glad you got it to work. If the answer provided helped feel free to mark it as a solution so future users can find it easier.